# _doPostBack is undefined JavaScript" for IE 11

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-4.0, internet-explorer-11

We were facing this error "_doPostBack is undefined JavaScript" for IE 11 , to fixed this we installed the Update for the Microsoft .NET Framework 4.0(OCT 2013). from http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2836939 on to our VM's & this issues is resolved, but when we install the same Microsoft updates on our web server, this issues is not resolved. so now we are in a confused state.
Our web server details are : Microsoft windows server 2003 R2 service pack 2 
please let us know if you need any more details. Any help is much a appreciated.

Thanks,
Punith

Comment: which control you are using ImageButton??

Comment: Its a dropdown (asp:DropDownList) &  Link button(asp:LinkButton). For more details, am posting the sample code.so this will be more clear.     <td align="right" nowrap="nowrap" style="width:50%;">   <asp:LinkButton ID="PreviousLinkButton" runat="server" CssClass="paginationText"
                            OnClick="PreviousLinkButton_Click" OnClientClick="CloseDiv();javascript:LoadingScreen.show();" Text="< Prev" meta:resourcekey="PreviousLinkButtonResource" ></asp:LinkButton>     <span ID="spnDivider" runat="server" style="text-align:center;color:black">|</span> </td>

Answer (score 1):

Solution for Net 4.0:

Follow the steps found here: http://rikter.com/articles/2013/12/internet-explorer-11-and-asp-net/

*But Use this browser file found here for step 1: http://blogs.telerik.com/docs/default-source/marinbratanov_files/telerik_ie11_browser_file_fix.zip?sfvrsn=2

Once I put this new file in my app_browsers folder, cleared temp files, ran regbrowsers.exe and did IIS reset, the site works in IE 11 without compatibility mode on.

Comment: Please copy the most important content in your answer, so it is not lost when links get stale.